# g compiler error with map<T, int>::iterator

Tags: c++, g++

While using Visual Studio 2012, the following code compiles without error (T is a template parameter):

```
pair<map<T, int>::iterator, bool> ret;
```

However, when I use g++, it throws the error message

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair
```

For some reason, it does not recognize `map<T, int>::iterator` as a type. How should I fix this for g++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that the qualified id `map<T, int>::iterator` is indeed a type ( *it can be a static member* )

```
pair<typename map<T, int>::iterator, bool> ret;
     ^^^^^^^^
```

Seems like <strike>for once</strike> as always VS is doing deduction <strike>better</strike> incorrectly than g++.

Comment: The other guess is that VS doesn't check the template properly, but (incorrectly) waits until the type is instantiated.

Comment: @BoPersson Ya VS is doing it wrong. Because it definitely needs typename there.

Answer (score 2):

The default is to assume that a dependent name is not a type, unless you explicitly say so.

Use this to do that:

```
typename map<T, int>::iterator
```